# how to remove focus on button click in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

For a11y(accessibility) I added this css which I can't change .Below css is always present in my demo application. I don't have any control to change that css.

```
button:focus,
a:focus {
  outline-offset: 2px;
  outline-width: 2px !important;
  outline-style: dotted !important;
  outline-color: currentColor;
}
```

but issue is when I click on button it show me `outline` . how to remove that outline on button click .

to resolve this issue I saw two option .

1. use `blur` event on click .It hide the `outline` . **but for few second it show the outline** .this does not work for me
2. use this `pseudo`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible .but **it does not work on safari**

is there any better way or any custom. hook which remove focus on button click ?

Here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-lamarr-lz586?file=/src/styles.css:59-207

```
function handleProductNavigation(event) {
    btnRef.current.blur();
    console.log(btnRef.current.blur);
    //event.currentTarget.blur();
  }
```

Comment: That MDN page refers to a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible#polyfill) for Safari.  Maybe that can work for you?

Comment: `:focus-visible` is the way to go. And for Safari you can either introduce a polyfill or to add a `shame.css` with some good old hacking: `button:focus:not(:focus-visible) { outline-color: transparent !important; }`

Comment: can you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901731/cannot-focus-button-using-tab-key-navigation-on-safari/67901876#67901876

Comment: not working on safari browser ..I have already done all steps which is mentioned in answer https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-paper-k7bg3?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :focus-visible approach with a polyfill for Safari and old Chrome/Firefox versions:

https://github.com/WICG/focus-visible

That polyfill adds a `focus-visible` class to the elements that are focused using the keyboard.

Comment: can you please change codesandbox how to use polyfil

Comment: @user944513 I saw you created a question about not being able to focus the button at all because of the default Safari tabbing behavior. Did you manage to solve that? I may try to help you solve the style issue, but if it is about the default behavior issue, the polyfill will not be enough.