# Cannot focus button using tab key navigation on Safari

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

can you please tell me why focus not going to button or not indicating that focus is on button while using `TABS` in safari browser.

In chrome it is working fine. the problem is on `SAFARI` browser.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-paper-k7bg3?file=/src/styles.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

/* .js-focus-visible :focus:not(.focus-visible) {
  outline: 0;
} */

button:focus,
a:focus {
  outline-offset: 2px;
  outline-width: 2px !important;
  outline-style: dotted !important;
  outline-color: currentColor;
}

.App button:focus,
.App a:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
.App button:focus-visible,
.App a:focus-visible {
  outline-offset: 2px;
  outline-width: 2px !important;
  outline-style: dotted !important;
  outline-color: currentColor;
}

.js-focus-visible :focus:not(.focus-visible) {
  outline: none !important;
}

/*
  Optionally: Define a strong focus indicator for keyboard focus.
  If you choose to skip this step then the browser's default focus
  indicator will be displayed instead.
*/
.js-focus-visible .focus-visible:focus-visible {
  outline-offset: 2px;
  outline-width: 2px !important;
  outline-style: dotted !important;
  outline-color: currentColor;
}
```

Set to reproduce.

1. Focus to First input field then press `TAB` two times focus should go to button . In chrome it is going .But is safari It is not going why ?

I have already did below answer not working ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safari ignoring tabindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848390/safari-ignoring-tabindex)

Comment: no https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-paper-k7bg3?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: @Martin i already did the given steps .. are you ablw to see focus o button

Comment: And your elements certainly all have a non-negative tab-index attribute set?

Answer (score 10):

Because Mac (and Safari) both default to only allowing you to tab into text boxes and lists.

However there is an accessibility setting to enable [Full Keyboard Access](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchlae61a6de/13.0/mac/13.0).

#### macOS Ventura

This is under System Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard (under the Motor heading).

[image: ventura-accessibility-keyboard]

#### Older macOS versions

Most likely Catalina or before:

[image: full-keyboard-access-older-macos]

Note for posterity that Safari > Settings > Advanced (including in Ventura) has a `Press Tab to highlight each item on a webpage`, though that is not required to make the button in the [provided code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-paper-k7bg3?file=/src/styles.css) selectable.

[image: safari-settings-advanced-tab]

Source: https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2014/10/03/link-tabbing-firefox-osx.html

Comment: I did this steps are you able to see `buttons` focus

Comment: I have already did above steps .but not highlighing

Comment: something wrong in CSS . most important thing is I am not to change this thing `button:focus,
a:focus {
  outline-offset: 2px;
  outline-width: 2px !important;
  outline-style: dotted !important;
  outline-color: currentColor;
}` I can override but changed

Answer (score 0):

Safari has not enabled tabindex by default.

See this thread: [Safari ignoring tabindex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848390/14226292)